# Android - Globally assign function to gamepad key combination

Tags: java, android, gamepad

I'd like to set up an Android TV box (Lollipop 5.1.1) to be able to function just with an Old PlayStation controller. Unfortunately it doesn't have a dedicated home button. I'd like a solution which makes the device return to home screen on a key combination (like L3+R3)

I've never made a standalone Android App or Service before but I am more than willing to learn it with some kind help :)

May a service with game controller event listener work?

Comment: If you're okay with sacrificing a button, you can edit the keylayout (.kl) file for your gamepad to reassign one of the buttons to emit the Home keycode. There is an app called Tincore Keymapper that might be able to do what you want but I've never used it and can't vouch for it.

Comment: I don't really want to sacrifice any button, but editing the .kl file is a great idea. I didn't even know that there is such an option.
I wanted to solve this without using 3rd party apps like Tincore, it'd be an overkill for this, especially because (not counting this problem) the gamepad works just fine